# How can I find down-stream dependencies for Views?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

On SQL Server 2005, you're supposed to be able to find dependencies in Manglement Studio by right-clicking an object and choosing "View Dependencies". The dialog gives you a choice of "Objects that depend on this" (what I'm calling down-stream) or "Objects that this depends on" (up-stream).

Both directions seem to work adequately for Table objects, and View objects seem to report good information in the up-stream direction. The down-stream list for a View, however, appears to consist only of the View itself--even when I *know* that there are other dependents (in this case, another view).

Is there a way that I can find this information? I'm comfortable with writing queries against system tables if I have a clue about which to target....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try:

```
sp_depends YourViewName
```

if you get no results, drop and recreate your view and try again.  Dropping and recreating may work for the GUI but I didn't try there

this is a little slow (and not the best query), but give it a try:

```
DECLARE @Search  varchar(300)
SET @Search='yourViewName'
SELECT DISTINCT
    LEFT(so.name, 120) AS Object_Name,
    "object_type"=left(
          case so.type
        when 'U' then 'Table - User'
        when 'S' then 'Table - System'
        when 'V' then 'Table - View'
        when 'TR' then 'Trigger'
        when 'P' then 'Stored Procedure'
        when 'C' then 'Constraint - Check'
        when 'D' then 'Default'
        when 'K' then 'Key - Primary'
        when 'F' then 'Key - Foreign'
        when 'L' then 'Log'
        when 'R' then 'Rule'
        when 'RF' then 'Replication Filter stp'
        else '<<UNKNOWN '''+so.type+'''>>'
    end  -- case so.type
        ,50)
    FROM syscomments sc 
        INNER JOIN sysobjects so 
            ON so.id = sc.id
    WHERE
        text Like '%'+@Search+'%'
    ORDER BY 
        2,1
```

Comment: Excellent script. One recommendation, you need to add 'TF' for User-Defined Function to your CASE list. Otherwise, the object_type comes back as "<<UNKNOWN 'TF>>".  +1

Comment: I've accepted this for the script--it does do what I need. I only got up-stream dependincies from sp_depends, and I don't have rights to drop & re-create the view.

Comment: @ichiban, this script predates 'TF' for User-Defined Function.  I last updated when moving from  sybase to sql server!

Comment: @RolandTumble, I was able to see stored procedures that used views when I did sp_depends on views on my sql server 2005

Comment: @KM, good catch--when I went & checked and view that I *know* feeds an SP, it does show, both in sp_depends and in the GUI. But it seems that other (down-stream) views don't....